# What is a "CDR"?

Tags: definition

I'm reading on Vertica's web site (database vendor) that many of their customer use their database for "CDR" purposes.

**Question:** What is a "CDR"?

http://www.vertica.com/customers/success

Comment: Given the list of clients I would say "Call Detail Record", a standard used in the telecom world for billing. But I don't think this is the proper forum for this question.

Comment: Compact Disc Recordable :) Sorry, couldn't resist.

Comment: So tempted to tag this with "Lisp".

Answer (score 5):

It is the [Call Detail Record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_detail_record). A call between points A and B might get routed through a few switches and for each leg of that call a CDR gets generated. The final CDR would be a correlation of the CDRs from each leg. A CDR contains information pertaining to a call, such as:

- Calling Number
- Called Number
- Point Codes or Switch codes of the source switch
- Point Codes or Switch codes of the terminating switch
- Trunk Access Code
- Time stamps of different events during call setup and call tear down

There are lots of other fields in a CDR and most of them vary depending on the standard being used. For example- Most of the fields mentioned above pertain to an [ISUP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISDN_User_Part) call. The CDR for a GSM/GPRS call would differ.

I hope this helps.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

In that context, it is most likely a [Call Detail Record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_detail_record), as the clients are Vonage, Verizon, etc.